# Can't access ethernet connected Pi using Wifi connected laptop

Tags: networking, wifi, ssh, ethernet, ping

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian) and I use it to earn income by sharing my internet bandwidth, so I want maximum speed and latency.
That's why I connected it to my router using ethernet.
While my Windows laptop is connected to the router over Wi-fi.
Both of them got IP address from my router, but I can't seem to SSH or ping my Raspberry from my laptop - "Destination host unreachable"

I'm really newbie at this and don't understand much about networking...
I've googled for hours but haven't found a case like mine.
Any help please?

Comment: Add more facts/details

Comment: if you also connect your laptop using ethernet, can you ping the pi? I assume you've checked the pi's connection to the router and beyond

Comment: @JaromandaX Tried connecting my laptop using ethernet, and I can't ping my pi either, yes both devices can access the router and internet, but can't ping other devices with ethernet

Comment: Have you checked your router allows connections between devices? Some routers disable that by default.

Comment: I got this Fiberhome router directly from my ISP and it turns out they disabled the LAN binding.. I can't enable it because the checkmarks are greyed out.. I guess I have to contact them..

Comment: You need to add more information to your question. For example, have you checked the IP addresses? Have you made any changes to your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`? Are you using `dhcpcd`? Review the `ip` command & its arguments; route, etc.